# Best way to remove integer part of float number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, rounding

To remove integer part of float numbers i use:

```
update ACTIVITIES set TIME = TIME - FLOOR(TIME) --TIME is float
```

this works anyway in the calculation there is some errors due to floating point calculation.

**EDIT**: I cannot modify the schema, `TIME` must stay `float`.

The reason i need to do this is that because of a bug the float numbers become > 1 even if the decimal part is still ok. So i need to remove the integer part.

I cannot reproduce it now, but i remember i had something like:

`1.6666666667` becomes `0.6666542534`, while it should be `0.6666666667`.

Please note that this is legacy code so `TIME` is a float number, while if i'd write this from scratch i would use a `TIME` datatype.

So my question is: is this correct or can it be improved?

```
update ACTIVITIES set TIME = TIME - FLOOR(TIME)
```

Comment: Do you just simply want to truncate the integer part and keep decimals ? or is there any rounding you want?

Comment: Can you convert the column to decimal?

Comment: plesae note i added "-- TIME is float" for clarity. I must leave the column as a float column, i must run a maintenance script without mofifying the schema